# create a Selector SEL using block with no parameter in Xcode

Tags: ios, block, selector, nstimer

I am working on Blocks programming, i have created a block.

```
void(^paint)(void)=^(void){
    NSLog(@"Process ");
};
```

now i want to create a nstimer using the NSinvocation and NSMethodSignatiureas below.

```
 void(^startPainting)(id)=^(id self){
        **SEL selectorToCall=@selector(paint());**

        NSMethodSignature *methodSignature=[[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selectorToCall];
        NSInvocation *invocation=[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSignature];
        [invocation setSelector:selectorToCall];
        [invocation setTarget:self];

        [self setPaintTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 invocation:invocation repeats:YES] ];

    //    self.paintTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(paint:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    };
```

The problem here is i want to send and the block paint to SEL.As the current statement is giving error.Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.How i can pass this block to this selector ?

```
SEL selectorToCall=@selector(paint());
```

Comment: Read a beginner Objective-C tutorial. `@selector(paint)` is what you want.

Comment: did u see my query above ? I am asking for how can i pass a block to Selector not a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dispatch-queues instead of selectors, works the same way and much better than the delay caused by firing a selector:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), paint);
```

Regards
Heider